# htaccess - 301 redirect with GET params

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, get, permalinks

I have a problem. The Сustomer, has changed permalinks on his site and ask me to set 301 redirect to old permalinks.

Old version: http://my-site.by/catalog/?branch=3855

New version: http://my-site.by/catalog/3855/

I tried in different ways, but it does not work...
Can anyone help me?

**UPD**

Oh, Sorry. Quite forgot to say.
I'm tired to pick up and do this on PHP side :)

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/?branch=') !== false)
{
  header(«HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently»);
  header(«Location: www.my-site.by/catalog/».str_replace("/catalog/?branch=","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/");
  exit();
}
```

someone else may be needed.

Comment: I tried to play with parameters:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[?]?branch=(.*)[&|$] [NC]
RewriteRule /catalog/ http://aleshka.by/catalog/%1/ [R=301,L]`
or
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^branch=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://aleshka.by/catalog/%1/ [R=301]`

but nothing has helped...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you htaccess :

```
# 301 Redirect - url to url
    RewriteRule http://my-site.by/catalog/?branch=3855  http://my-site.by/catalog/3855/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

And if you want to do this for all this kind of url :

```
# 301 Redirect - Dynamic Rewriting
RewriteRule ^catalog/?branch=([0-9]+)$ catalog/$1/
```

Comment: You need `R=301` in that second redirect too.

Comment: tried with 301: RewriteRule ^catalog/?branch=([0-9]+)$ catalog/$1/ [R=301] the same result.